# Generic static cache, and Covariance

Tags: c#, generics, caching, reflection, covariance

I was trying to build a static generic cache which is going to hold method info of several methods of the form Apply(Event e). A similar code is used in RedirectToWhen, from CQRS Lokad framework.

The problem is that the generic cache doesn't consider derived classes if any. This is a simple test that shows the undesired behavior:

```
  [TestMethod]
    public void TestGenericsInheritance()
    {
        var sut = new DerivedFromAbstractType();
        Utils.UsefulMethod<DerivedFromAbstractType>(sut);
        Assert.AreEqual(10, sut.Value);
    }

    public abstract class AbstractType
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedFromAbstractType : AbstractType
{
    public void AnyOtherMethod()
    {
        Value = 10;
    }
}

public static class Utils
{
    public static void UsefulMethod<T>(T instance)
    {
        MethodInfo info = typeof(T)
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(m => m.Name == "AnyOtherMethod")
            .Where(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 0).FirstOrDefault();
        info.Invoke(instance,null);
     }
}
```

typeof(T) returns AbstractType, so I can't use it to build a generic static cache. 
How could I get a generic cache for methods awared of derived types?

Comment: Not sure why `typeof(T)` would return `AbstractType` for you. According to both the rules of C#, as well as my own tests, `typeof(T)` is `DerivedFromAbstractType`, and in fact `sut.Value` is 10 after running `UsefulMethod()`. Perhaps if you could show us in more detail what you need to accomplish, and where your attempts are going wrong?

Comment: It is great to here that. Now I have to guess why do I get AbstractType instead of DerivedFromAbstractType!! I'm using .Net Framework 4.0.30319.

Comment: What I want to accomplish is shown in the [following code](https://gist.github.com/1047419). In other words, caching for each concrete type, a couple of methods created by convention within that type that I find using reflection. They are going to be called several times so I expect a performance improvement thanks to caching.

Comment: I have executed it in a different environment (Windows XP 64bit) and it works properly. Could it be a .Net Framework configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
instance.GetType()
```

if instance is not null and typeof(T) os instance is null.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is necro-ing a bit, but I had the same problem, with typeof(T) returning the base type. This is useful when wanting to create a BaseAggregate which implements an Emit/Apply pattern. I solved it like this :

```
 private static class Cache
        {
            private static readonly IDictionary<Type, IDictionary<Type, MethodInfo>> _dict =
                new Dictionary<Type, IDictionary<Type, MethodInfo>>();

            public static IDictionary<Type, MethodInfo> GetDictionaryForType(Type type)
            {
                if (_dict.ContainsKey(type))
                {
                    return _dict[type];
                }
                var dict = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .Where(m => m.Name == "When")
                    .Where(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 1)
                    .ToDictionary(m => m.GetParameters().First().ParameterType, m => m);
                _dict.Add(type, dict);
                return dict;
            }
        }
```

This still caches nicely, and `object.GetType()` returns the correct type to be fed into this method.